# Blank results when iterating through a non-empty array in angular template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

EDIT: I made changes in the push method but it still did not work
I am making get request to an api and pushing each of the responses to an array. The array is visible when logged to console. On printing the length of the array in the template length comes out to be 5. But when I try to iterate through it using ngFor no output is being displayed

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Quote} from 'src/app/models/quote';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StockpriceService {

  url1='https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/'; 
  url2='?apikey=efa24b272821b542c459557332c02a1e';
  

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
  }

  //alpha apikey="VETRGM94G70WQGX9";


  getQuote(symbol:string) //load data from api
  {
      return this.http.get<Quote>(this.url1 + symbol + this.url2);
  }
}
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{Quote} from 'src/app/models/quote';
import{StockpriceService} from 'src/app/services/stockprice.service';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stocks',
  templateUrl: './stocks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stocks.component.css']
})
export class StocksComponent implements OnInit {

  stocks: Array<Quote>=[];
  symbols=['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'FB', 'AMZN', 'TWTR'];
  constructor(private serv:StockpriceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.symbols.forEach(symbol => {

     this.serv.getQuote(symbol).subscribe(
        (data:Quote)=>{
          console.log(data);
          this.stocks.push(
            {
              symbol:data.symbol,
              price:data.price,
              volume:data.volume
            }
          );
  
        }
      )
      
    });

    console.log('stocks array is')
    console.log(this.stocks);
    
  }

}
```

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let stock of stocks">

              {{stock.symbol}}
              {{stock.price}}
 </div>
```

sample api response

```
[ {
  "symbol" : "AAPL",
  "price" : 126.81380000,
  "volume" : 36245456
} ]
```

Accordingly I have an interface defined for it as

```
    export interface Quote{
    symbol:string;
    price:number;
    volume:number;
}
```

Comment: `this.stocks.push(...data)`

Comment: @eko made changes to the push method

Comment: it needs to be `data[0].symbol`.. Please read the response from your api carefully

Comment: @eko that yeilds another error- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Quote'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Quote'.

Comment: Ok you are telling in your question that the response is an array of a Quote object. If you use `this.stocks.push(...data)` then that array is going to be spread while you're pushing the data

Comment: Your response type is not `Quote` it is `Array<Quote>`

Comment: Change `(data:Quote)=>{` to `(data:Array<Quote>)=>{` and please apply my first comment to your code.

Comment: @eko works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :-) You can answer your own question and mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
this.serv.getQuote(symbol).subscribe((data: Quote[]) => {
     console.log(data);
     this.stocks.push(...data);
});
```